# How to compute a signature for a changing `std::map`

Tags: c++, algorithm

We have 5 servers each running the same service that produces a `std::map`. Each item in the `std::map` is composed of a unique integer as key and a double as its corresponding value. In order to check the consistency across different machines, we need to constantly check the equality of the `std::map` among five servers.

Each `std::map` stores 2 millions different items and it keeps changing during the day. The naive way to compare the value is as follows:

```
compare S1 with S2, S3, S4, S5
compare S2 with S3, S4, S5
compare S3 with S4, S5
compare S4 with S5
```

This is N*N complexity and whenever a single value in the map is changed, the O(N) comparison has to be redone.

A better idea is to build a signature for each map and the map comparison is reduced to float number comparison in the end. There are two challenges here:

1. how to build a single value based on a huge map
2. how to compute this value incrementally based on the changing map

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is it supposed to detect accidental desynchronization only, or also defeat intelligent adversaries?

Comment: if S1==S2, S1==S3, S1==S4, S1==S5 then all are equal so O(N). If not, regard them as hugely composite keys and sort them to divide them into groups for O(N log N)

Answer (score 2):

Since the maps are apparently always-consistent, it follows naturally that the same modifications are happening in the same order.

This means that you can use a (secure) hash of the sequence of modifications in lieu of comparing the maps themselves. For each modification, you update `H = hash(H | Key | Value )` and then compare `H1`...`H5`.

The initial choice of H doesn't matter, the main requirement is that all servers should start with the same H value and with the maps in the same state.

Answer (score 1):

Following on Bryan Chen's comments a simple hash which could be computed incrementally is as follows:

Given a hash function h() compute h(len(k) || k || v) where || means append, len(k) is the length of k, and k and v are the key and value of a single key-value pair. Then keep track of the sum or xor of all key-value pairs in the hash map, maintaining it by incrementing, decrementing, or xor-ing to it when you add or delete a key-value pair.

Certainly not secure against an adversary that knows or can find out h(len(k) || k || v) for hash-value pairs. It appears safe in other circumstances, if h() can modeled as an idea random function - but I wouldn't bet much on this until other people have looked at this idea. If you are worried, you could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code with a secret key to get a secret h().

Answer (score 0):

The incremental hash is clearly the way to go.

Unless, for whatever reason, it isn't. Another way to do this is to serialize and hash the whole tree. Boost provides a handy serialization function and there is an MD5 hash generator available [here](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function). Combining these two gives you a way to hash any map at any time. The code below will compile with:

```
g++ test.cpp md5.cpp --std=c++11 -lboost_serialization
```

You can, of course, substitute the MD5 hash for another of your choosing.

```
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include "md5.h"


int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> map = {{1,2}, {2,1}};
  std::stringstream ss;
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oarch(ss);
  oarch << map;

  std::cout<<md5(ss.str())<<std::endl;
}
```